# LiPo Charging Voltage and Operating Voltage problem

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have 3 Lithium Polymer batteries. I would like to hook them up in series. The voltage would equate to 11.1V. If I have a LiPo charger does it require 11.1V input to charge them?

Comment: It depends on what your charger needs to work. Write brand, model, datasheet if present or link to specifications.

Comment: That 3.7 V per cell is the cell voltage when it is almost discharged. A fully charged cell has a voltage of 4.1 to 4.3 V (depends on the cell). So a linear 3-cell charged would need almost 13 V and that is excluding some voltage drop for the charging circuit. In practice at least 14 V would be needed. Only if the charger has a switching converter can it charge from a lower voltage.

Comment: @FakeMoustache the OP may be asking about LiFePo4 cells with nominal voltage of 3.2V and charging voltage of 3.65V, but we may never be sure unless he writes few more words. *The question was first posted on StackOverflow before it was moved here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I have a LiPo charger does it require 11.1V input to charge them?

Not necessarily. If the battery is a standard Lipo type then it will require 4.2V*3 = 12.6V to get a full charge. However some chargers have a booster circuit which enables them to run from a lower voltage (typically 12V).

More sophisticated chargers have programmable current and voltage to handle different batteries. Many also have a balancer circuit to equalize the voltages on each cell, which is essential when cells are charged in series because even a tiny over-voltage can damage a cell. A serous imbalance can even cause the battery to blow up and set fire to anything nearby! (this is not theoretical - I know several people that this has happened to).

Adding a balancer cable is highly recommended, both for balancing and checking the cell voltages. Even if you don't use a balancing charger, you must ensure that all the cells have equal voltage when fully charged. With a balance cable installed you can charge each cell individually if required.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend charging a LiPo battery with a simple voltage charge. The normal charging regime is:

1. Constant current, then
2. Balance, then
3. Constant voltage until terminal charge state is reached, then
4. Disconnect charging voltage

LiPo batteries do not like float charges. Taking shortcuts can result in damage to the battery or a catastrophic failure resulting in an explosion or fire. I recommend that you acquire a properly constructed charger for your LiPo battery. A LiPo charging/storage bag is a good accessory to avoid spreading damage should a catastrophic failure of the battery occur.